# adding code into CKeditor when clicking on external button

Tags: jquery, textarea, ckeditor

Here's the scenario: a user is typing into CKeditor, just outside the editor there is a button, when pressed jQuery kicks in $(".button").click(function... and this appends some text or whatever is defined by the button into the same place where the user was typing in the CKeditor.

Has anyone got any ideas if this is even possible?

Comment: There is JavaScript API for CKEditor.

Answer (score 2):

Possible and simple.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertText("Magical ponies await!")
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml("<hr/>");
```

Getting a reference to the editor is trivial (I hope). This example works for example in the official CKEditor demo.

The CKEditor 4 API is very well documented. See the documentation for `insertHtml()` at http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml

---

Also, the content you are adding must be allowed in the Advanced Content Filter feature of CKEditor. See the documentation at http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter

If you don't care about ACF and just want everything to work, you can set the ACF configuration to allow all content by setting the configuration value to `true` with `config.allowedContent = true;`.

Comment: When i try with p or strong tags it works, but with hr or links it doesn't. Is there any config when i can say what tags i can use?

Comment: That's very strange. It could be that those tags are not allowed, but it seems odd that you would have them blocked. Oh well, it could be! The content filtering system in modern versions of CKE is called Advanced Content Filter: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter To set the config to allow all depends a little on your setup, but you can try `allowedContent: true` or `config.allowedContent = true;` - whichever method is applicable to you. Examine your configuration and have a look at the link, the Documentation is really quite good :)